# How to write parallelly into a container

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, c++14

I'm working with C++14 and I don't know how to write parallelly into a container with multi-threading.

Let's say I have such a map: `std::map<int, int> mp {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}}` and a function as below:

```
void updateValue(int& value) {
    value = xxx; // heavy calculation
}
```

Then I try to create three threads:

```
std::vector<std::thread> vec;
for (auto& ele : mp) {
    vec.emplace_back(std::thread(updateValue, std::ref(ele.second)));
}
```

However, the problem is that `std::map` is not thread-safe.

So it seems that I need to add a lock in the function `updateValue`. But if I do this, the function has to be called one by one, just like a single-thread.

It there some method to allow me to use multi-threading in this case?

Comment: Note that the behaviour of `updateValue` is unclear since it does not modify the map itself (does the parameter reference a value of the hashmap?) and we do not know what "heavy calculation" is supposed to do (does it changes the hashmap?). Could you try to redesign your algorithm so each thread works on a local (copy of the) hashmap (then merged)?

Comment: @JérômeRichard I think it does modify the map beause of `std::ref(ele.second)`?

Comment: @JérômeRichard If I understand you correctly, I have to modify the function `updateValue()`? like `updateValue(std::map<>)`?

Comment: Thread currently call `func` and not `updateValue`. Is it a mistake? If not, then what is the relation between the two? If threads calls `updateValue` directly, then you just need to lock the `value = xxx;` instruction. if `xxx` read `value` then it depends of the content of ``xxx`. Please provide a minimal *reproducible example*.

Comment: If every thread operates on a different element of a `map<>`, then you don't need to sync access. You have to make sure that those elements are not accessed though, including deleting them. IOW, pay attention to error handling/stack unwinding in the case of exceptions.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yeah my bad, it was a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is safe as-is, and doesn't require any additional synchronization.

> **[container.requirements.dataraces]/2** Notwithstanding **[res.on.data.races]**, implementations are required to avoid data races when the contents of the contained object in different elements in the same container, excepting `vector<bool>`, are modified concurrently.